# wants to get my next value after choosing operator in calculator in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am stuck in how to get the next value in calculator from that variable which I used to get previous value.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props)
    {
        this.state={
            value:'0',
            previousvalue:'',
            nextvalue:''
        }
    };
    this.handleclick=this.handleclick.bind(this);
    this.operation=this.operation.bind(this);
}

handleclick(digit)
{        
    this.setState({value:this.state.value==='0'?String(digit):this.state.value + digit});
    console.log('helo click fire',this.state.value);
    if(digit==='00')
    {
        this.setState({value:'0'});
        console.log('are you coming');
    }
}

operation(operator)
{
    console.log('operator coming',operator);
    // this.setState({ans:this.state.value,operator,this.state.value})
    const previousvalue=this.state.value;
    console.log('this is my previous value',previousvalue);
    if(operator)
    {
        const nextValue=this.state.value;
        console.log('this is my next value',nextValue);
        //it gives my previous value how i store init my new value ??
    }

}
```

How can I get the next value from the same variable which gives me the previous value?

Comment: store previous value in state. state = { value: ..., previousValue: ... }. Whenever you change value using setState, pass previousValue: this.state to the partialState argument (first argument of setState).

Comment: can u please write getable syntax ?

Comment: Explain me your context, what you are trying to do. Then I would be able to give you an answer. (edit your post)